# Find and replace linefeed after any character

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to delete linefeeds that come after any character in a text file, but not those that come after a carriage return.

This deletes all of them:

```
$content = Get-Content -raw "in.txt"
($content).Replace("`n","") | Set-Content out.txt -Force
```

In notepad++ I find them by searching for `$\n`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Thanks [@Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) for the negative lookbehind hint.

```
($content).Replace("(?<!`r)`n","") | Set-Content out.txt -Force
```

Comment: @Aaron You are right, I fixed my answer and now use a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read the text file like this which returns one string for whole file:

$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("in.txt")

Now it works!